Reply All to Opened Email in Microsoft Outlook
I have a MS Access database that has a control button that opens a hyperlink to an Outlook email file saved on the server for all to use and respond.
I'm looking to, when the control button is pressed, open the email and then Reply All to it.
Scouring the web I learned the ActiveInspector.CurrentItem should accomplish the open part.
I found a way to use ActiveExplorer to reply all, but that works with whichever email is highlighted in the Outlook pane not the current opened email.
My code for the ActiveExplorer. How can I change it to the ActiveInspector or how do I reply all to the opened email?
Private Sub Command302_Click()
Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oExp As Outlook.Explorer
Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olReply As MailItem ' Reply
Dim olRecip As Recipient ' Add Recipient

FollowHyperlink Me.Text276
Set objApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Set oExp = objApp.ActiveExplorer
For Each olItem In objApp.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    Set olReply = olItem.ReplyAll
    Set olRecip = olReply.Recipients.add("me@email.com") ' Recipient Address
    olRecip.Type = olCC
    olReply.HTMLBody = "Test Response " & vbCrLf & olReply.HTMLBody
    olReply.Display
Next olItem
End Sub


Use
Set olReply = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.ReplyAll

Also keep in mind that code like olReply.HTMLBody = "Test Response " & vbCrLf & olReply.HTMLBody cannot possibly produce well formed HTML. The two must be merged.

Dimitry thanks for your help and the slow response. I keep getting a Run time Error 91 Object variable or with block not set. Here is what I have.
Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oInsp As Outlook.Inspector
Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olReply As MailItem ' Reply
Dim olRecip As Recipient ' Add Recipient

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
FollowHyperlink Me.Text276
Set objApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Set oInsp = objApp.ActiveInspector
Set olReply = objApp.Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.ReplyAll - 'Error Happens Here


Which line raises that exception? Do you have a message displayed in an inspector (that is what my code uses) or only a messages selected in an explorer message list? Or do you mean you edit a message in an inline editor?

The "Set olReply = objApp.Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.ReplyAll " raises the Error 91. I have the email they reply to open in  a window before the code runs. Not sure if that is open in an inspector or an inline editor. From what I read I assumed it was an inspector, last opened email. Thanks again.

You have an extraneous Application (needs to Set olReply = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.ReplyAll), but that should not make a difference. Try to break that line into separate lines. What do you see if you try MsgBox TypeName(objApp.ActiveInspector), MsgBox TypeName(objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem), MsgBox TypeName(objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.ReplyAll) ?

So, is it possible that the hyperlink that opens the email doesn't open it as fast as the code? If I let the code open the email I get: "Nothing" (Inspector), "MailItem"(CurrentItem), and "MailItem" (CurrentItem.ReplyAll). If I leave the email open I get: "Inspector" (Inspector), "MailItem"(CurrentItem), and "MailItem" (CurrentItem.ReplyAll). Not sure how to make the code wait till the email opens?

What code? Your code never displays a message. If the inspector is closed of course Application.ActiveInspector will be null. Do you mean you open an MSG file programmatically (ShellExecute etc.) and then immediately try to access the inspector? Of course it will take some time for Outlook to open and display the message.
